# Access Laravel Project on Network Machine

Tags: php, laravel, networking, sails.js, ubuntu-14.04

i am new to laravel and basically i am a nodejs developer, i basically develop application in sailsjs and i access my sailjs application on another machine within same network by using my machine ip on which the project is running.

like i lift main salsjs application on A machine using sails `lift --port 1334` and then goto another machine B within same network and access is with my A machine ip , like `192.168.10.2:1334`

now i want to do the same thing with laravel, i've lifted my server using laravel command

```
ahsan@ahsan-Inspiron-N5110:~/Desktop/Development/laravell/laravel$ sudo php artisan serve --port 1334
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:1334
```

and now the application is running on 1334 port and when i try to access it from machine B within same network it just says `unble to connect`.

Please let me knowo what do i need to do to access it over network with my machine A ip address.

Thanks.

Note: i am using UBUNTU on Machine  A and have access to sailsjs application on Machine B which is windows based but not the laravel application access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1334
```

or

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.10.2 --port 1334
```

in most cases you will need permissions (sudo) to start this. If its not working, check your firewall (iptables)

Comment: I'm trying to do this same thing on windows machines. It's giving the error: E:\laravelProject\laravel>php artisan serve --host 192.168.0.200 --port 8000
Laravel development server started: <http://192.168.0.200:8000>
[Sat Aug 25 14:56:17 2018] Failed to listen on 192.168.0.200:8000 (reason: The requested address is not valid in its context.
)

Comment: Sorry, actually I was trying to run the command from another machine instead of host. Is there any way so that I can start this host server from another machine itself? Like host IP will be 200 and command will be typed in machine with IP 110 or any other machine on same network.